# Increment SQL column based on another

Tags: sql-server

Given that I have a query like this:

```
select employeeid as id, department as dep from employee where department in (...) 
order by department
```

I would like to have an extra column that increments for every 3 departments so that the result looks something like this:

```
id dep        magic
1  Accounting 0
30 Accounting 0
66 HR         0
67 HR         0
33 HR         0
2  Sales      0
9  IT         1
12 R&D        1
19 Design     1
45 QA         2
46 QA         2
```

I have tried with various row number functions, over() and other voodoo, but I cant seem to get it right. Hope you can help me with this one!

Edit: So this was not as straight forward as I had hoped. The example above probably didnt capture all the issues involved in my case.
So this is the real query that I am running:

```
select    sdi.sdcid
         ,sdi.keyid1
         ,sdi.paramlistid
         ,sdi.paramlistversionid
         ,sdi.variantid
         ,sdi.dataset
         ,sdi.paramid
         ,sdi.paramtype
         ,sdi.replicateid
         ,sd.sdidataid
        --(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sd.sdidataid asc) -1) /3 partition
         from sdidataitem sdi
         left join sdidata sd on 
         sdi.keyid1 = sd.keyid1 
         and sdi.keyid2 = sd.keyid2 
         and sdi.keyid3 = sd.keyid3 
         and sdi.paramlistid = sd.paramlistid 
         and sdi.paramlistversionid = sd.paramlistversionid 
         and sdi.variantid = sd.variantid 
         and sdi.dataset = sd.dataset 
         where sd.sdidataid in (select top 30 sdidataid from sdidata) 
         and sdi.u_analysserieid is null
         order by sd.sdidataid asc
```

when I run the query with the partition column I get the following error: `Cannot find either column "sd" or the user-defined function or aggregate "sd.sdidataid", or the name is ambiguous.`
This is  the code to create the two tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE [lv2056d].[sdidata]  ( 
[sdcid]                     nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid1]                    nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid2]                    nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid3]                    nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[paramlistid]               nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[paramlistversionid]        nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[variantid]                 nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[dataset]                   numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,
[limitruleid]               nvarchar(40) NULL,
[limitruleversionid]        nvarchar(40) NULL,
[modifiableflag]            nvarchar(1) NULL,
[approvalsequenceflag]      nvarchar(1) NULL,
[approvalpassrule]          nvarchar(20) NULL,
[condition]                 nvarchar(80) NULL,
[availabilityflag]          nvarchar(1) NULL,
[workflowid]                nvarchar(40) NULL,
[workflowversionid]         nvarchar(40) NULL,
[workflowinstance]          numeric(18,0) NULL,
[usersequence]              numeric(18,0) NULL,
[notes]                     nvarchar(2000) NULL,
[auditsequence]             numeric(18,0) NULL,
[auditdeferflag]            nvarchar(1) NULL,
[tracelogid]                nvarchar(40) NULL,
[createdt]                  datetime NULL,
[createby]                  nvarchar(40) NULL,
[createtool]                nvarchar(20) NULL,
[moddt]                     datetime NULL,
[modby]                     nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_datasetstatus]           nvarchar(20) NULL,
[modtool]                   nvarchar(20) NULL,
[s_notebookreference]       nvarchar(20) NULL,
[s_assignedanalyst]         nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_instrumentid]            nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_icoverriddenflag]        nvarchar(1) NULL,
[s_retestedflag]            nvarchar(1) NULL,
[s_remeasuredflag]          nvarchar(1) NULL,
[s_remeasureinstance]       numeric(18,0) NULL,
[s_qcbatchid]               nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_qcbatchitemid]           nvarchar(20) NULL,
[trackitemid]               nvarchar(40) NULL,
[scheduleplanid]            nvarchar(40) NULL,
[scheduleplanitemid]        nvarchar(40) NULL,
[uniquenessflag]            nvarchar(1) NULL,
[approvalflag]              nvarchar(1) NULL,
[sdidataid]                 nvarchar(40) NULL,
[sourceworkitemid]          nvarchar(40) NULL,
[sourceworkiteminstance]    numeric(18,0) NULL,
[s_cancellableflag]         nvarchar(1) NULL,
[documentid]                nvarchar(40) NULL,
[documentversionid]         nvarchar(40) NULL,
[blockflag]                 nvarchar(1) NULL,
[activeflag]                nvarchar(1) NULL,
[s_assigneddepartment]      nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_instrumentusedflag]      nvarchar(1) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [xpksdidata] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([sdcid],[keyid1],[keyid2],[keyid3],[paramlistid],[paramlistversionid],[variantid],[dataset]))
GO
CREATE TABLE [lv2056d].[sdidataitem]  ( 
[sdcid]                 nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid1]                nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid2]                nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[keyid3]                nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[paramlistid]           nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[paramlistversionid]    nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[variantid]             nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[dataset]               numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,
[paramid]               nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
[paramtype]             nvarchar(80) NOT NULL,
[replicateid]           numeric(18,0) NOT NULL,
[aliasid]               nvarchar(80) NULL,
[mandatoryflag]         nvarchar(1) NULL,
[datatypes]             nvarchar(20) NULL,
[enteredvalue]          numeric(28,10) NULL,
[enteredtext]           nvarchar(255) NULL,
[enteredunits]          nvarchar(40) NULL,
[operatorrule]          nvarchar(255) NULL,
[transformvalue]        numeric(28,10) NULL,
[transformdt]           datetime NULL,
[transformtext]         nvarchar(255) NULL,
[transformrule]         nvarchar(4000) NULL,
[displayvalue]          nvarchar(255) NULL,
[displayunits]          nvarchar(40) NULL,
[displayformat]         nvarchar(255) NULL,
[rangeoperator]         nvarchar(20) NULL,
[enteredqualifier]      nvarchar(20) NULL,
[entrysdcid]            nvarchar(40) NULL,
[entryreftypeid]        nvarchar(40) NULL,
[calcrule]              nvarchar(4000) NULL,
[measurementactionid]   nvarchar(40) NULL,
[releasedflag]          nvarchar(1) NULL,
[valuestatus]           nvarchar(20) NULL,
[condition]             nvarchar(80) NULL,
[transformdeferflag]    nvarchar(1) NULL,
[textcolor]             numeric(18,0) NULL,
[usersequence]          numeric(18,0) NULL,
[notes]                 nvarchar(2000) NULL,
[auditsequence]         numeric(18,0) NULL,
[auditdeferflag]        nvarchar(1) NULL,
[tracelogid]            nvarchar(40) NULL,
[createdt]              datetime NULL,
[createby]              nvarchar(40) NULL,
[createtool]            nvarchar(20) NULL,
[moddt]                 datetime NULL,
[modby]                 nvarchar(40) NULL,
[modtool]               nvarchar(20) NULL,
[s_acoverriddenflag]    nvarchar(1) NULL,
[s_analystid]           nvarchar(40) NULL,
[s_qcevalstatus]        nvarchar(20) NULL,
[displayvalueformat]    nvarchar(255) NULL,
[calcexcludeflag]       nvarchar(1) NULL,
[sdidataitemid]         nvarchar(40) NULL,
[instrumentid]          nvarchar(40) NULL,
[instrumentfieldid]     nvarchar(20) NULL,
[activeflag]            nvarchar(1) NULL,
[externalreference]     nvarchar(255) NULL,
[resulttimeoffset]      numeric(28,10) NULL,
[u_analysserieid]       nvarchar(20) NULL,
[u_showindataentry]     nvarchar(20) NULL,
[w_instrumentid]        nvarchar(20) NULL,
[u_defvalset]           nvarchar(20) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [xpksdidataitem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([sdcid],[keyid1],[keyid2],[keyid3],[paramlistid],[paramlistversionid],[variantid],[dataset],[paramid],[paramtype],[replicateid]))
GO
```

Comment: May I ask you the purpose of the Magic? :)

Comment: this is a contrived example far from reality :) I will use it to fetch values from an array in my code (ugly)

Comment: ewwwww... But you gotta do what you gotta do, right? If you want a different look maybe on your (ugly) code, I'm up for that :) So if you provide the bigger picture (not all), we might put you on a different path? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...) / 3

```
select employeeid as id, department as dep , 
(row_number() over (order by department asc) -1) /3 partition
from employee 
where department in (...) 
order by department
```

About your query.
1) you seem to miss comma after first field
2) better use join if you really joining tables, just for clarity

```
select sd.sdidataid, (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sd.sdidataid asc) -1) /3 partition 
from sdidataitem sdi inner join sdidata sd on 
    sdi.keyid1 = sd.keyid1 (... more column restrictions) 
and sdi.dataset = sd.dataset 
where sd.sdidataid in (select top 30 sdidataid from sdidata) 
and sdi.u_analysserieid is null 
order by sd.sdidataid asc
```

Comment: @danihp -  He told he want value to be incremented for every 3 departments. I did exactly that. You will have value incremented for every three rows , not departments

Comment: @oskbor -  so show you query, how could i know what is wrong with it.

Comment: So this is the real query which fails: select        
sdidata.sdidataid
            (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sdidata.sdidataid asc) -1) /3 partition
             from sdidataitem,sdidata 
             where sdidataitem.keyid1 = sdidata.keyid1 
             (... more column restrictions)
             and sdidataitem.dataset = sdidata.dataset 
             and sdidata.sdidataid in (select top 30 sdidataid from sdidata) 
             and sdidataitem.u_analysserieid is null
             order by sdidata.sdidataid asc

Comment: Cannot find either column "sdidata" or the user-defined function or aggregate "sdidata.sdidataid", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: @oskbor does query work with row_number and without this `sd.sdidataid in (select top 30 sdidataid from sdidata)` condition ? If yes, add alias for subquery sd.sdidataid in `(select top 30 sdidataid from sdidata sd2) `

Comment: @vittore Nope that didnt help unfortuneately, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tab table (id int,dep varchar(50))
insert into @tab Values(1,'Accounting'),(2,'Accounting'),(3,'Accounting'),(4,'AAA'),(5,'BBB'),(6,'ccc'),(7,'ddd'),(8,'eee'),(9,'fff');


Select t.*,a.Magic
from @tab t
join
(
Select dep,(ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dep) -1)/3 as Magic
from @tab
group by dep
) a on a.dep=t.dep
order by t.dep
```